# Creating Procedure/Task Run in Snowflake to stage a Table and Merge to Target (without unique ids)

Tags: merge, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, procedure

I am having a conundrum coming up with an automated solution for a Merge that ensures I am not inserting duplicate values (without the use of unique row identifier).

My task is to create a final aggregate table that is appended over time as new data arrives, based on a join from two tables. I have confirmed the aggregates are correct and what is needed within a view for testing. My idea was to create stage table that is well ordered and partitioned by date, which using the view join logic, takes data from the current date and back 1 day, since the main table updates twice daily. Ideally stage will capture 2 whole days worth of data so nothing is missed just in case.

An example of the stage table looks like/contains which matches the 'full' target table that will be appended (context: for the full table it lists every patient for a given date and sometimes they are repeat distinct visitors, so there could be 47 persons on the 25th, and the count reflects 47, the unique count col is a special case by window function and unique rows):

| Date | Source | Patient_ID | Status | Totals_Patients_Count | Unique_Patients_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-25 | HAL | aaa23ef | TRUE | 47 | 30 |
| 2023-09-24 | DAL | aaa21ef | FALSE | 23 | 15 |
| 2023-09-23 | CCL | aaa20ef | TRUE | 20 | 10 |

However, if I create a target table based on the final columns, that does not have a unique ID (the joined tables do not have unique row IDs), would a Merge still work without the need for one? Originally I thought to use an artificially created row_id, however that does not guarantee they will always be the same with the target table. I tested that with a merge and the counts became off due to re-issuing the row_ids everytime the stage is created (the ON condition was stg.row_id = tgt_row_id).

My second idea for merge is below by removing artificially created "row_id" and simply merge on patient ids (which are unique in and of themselves, and all patient_ids are selected for a given date, and then also by the date itself):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE stg_to_target_merge()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
BEGIN

MERGE INTO target_table tgt
USING (SELECT * FROM stage_table) AS src ON tgt.DATE = src.DATE
AND tgt.patient_id = src.patient_ID
WHEN MATCHED (do nothing)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (tgt.cols)
VALUES (src.cols)

RETURN 'Merge completed'
END;
```

The Task runs are simply:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK tsk1
WAREHOUSE = 'custom_wh'
SCHEDULE = 'custom cron schedule'
AS
CALL create_stg_tbl_proc();

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK tsk2
WAREHOUSE = 'custom_wh'
AFTER tsk1
AS
CALL stg_to_target_merge()
```

I am aware there are far more complicated and robust merge automations from looking around, however I feel this use case is different than other examples I have found. A Dynamic Table (new snowflake feature) would also not suffice since Dynamic Tables do a full truncate when JOIN logic is used, which may eventually take longer and use more compute credits over time as the data select grows.

Comment: Hi - it’s not clear, to me, what your actual question is? You seem to have a solution and if you are asking if it will work then what’s stopping you testing it and finding out?

Comment: One of the problems is with this solution when performing a Merge, I often receive an error "Duplicate row detected on DML operation".  I need it to skip where it finds a duplicate and continue.  (find duplicate, skip that one, continue, if another duplicate, skip and continue until the end)

Comment: Your process obviously requires that the row to be updated in the target can be uniquely identified - how you do that is up to you based on your knowledge of the data. If you have duplicate source records and that is legitimate then just set ERROR_ON_NONDETERMINISTIC_MERGE=FALSE, if it’s not legitimate then you need to amend your source data to not produce duplicates, based on your knowledge of your data

Comment: Yes, I think that is the main thing problem I need to solve - my target table needs rows to have a unique identifier.  I could add a sequence to the Target Table, however I don't see how that will work with a staging table that is recreated every day grabbing a specific range of days from the source.